# What is the proper way to create a new generic struct?

Tags: generics, struct, rust

I'm trying to make a generic struct that can be initialized to something of type `T`. It looks like this:

```
pub struct MyStruct<T> {
    test_field: Option<T>,
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}

impl MyStruct<T> {
    fn new(new_age: i32, new_name: String) -> MyStruct<T> {
        MyStruct<T> {
            test_field: None,
            age: new_age,
            name: new_name,
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Among other errors, I get:

```
error: chained comparison operators require parentheses
 --> src/lib.rs:9:17
  |
9 |         MyStruct<T> {
  |                 ^^^^^
  |
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I **highly recommend** reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/). It covers basics like this, and the Rust team spent a lot of time to make it good! Specifically, the [section on generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html) would probably have helped here.

You don't need to use `<T>` when instantiating the struct. The type for `T` will be inferred. You will need to declare that `T` is a generic type on the `impl` block:

```
struct MyStruct<T> {
    test_field: Option<T>,
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}

impl<T> MyStruct<T> {
//  ^^^
    fn new(new_age: i32, new_name: String) -> MyStruct<T> {
        MyStruct {
            test_field: None,
            age: new_age,
            name: new_name,
        }
    }
}
```

As [DK. points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399953/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-a-new-generic-struct/30400004?noredirect=1#comment48887893_30400004), you could choose to specify the type parameter using the *turbofish* syntax (`::<>`):

```
MyStruct::<T> {
//      ^^^^^
    test_field: None,
    age: new_age,
    name: new_name,
}
```

Modern compiler versions actually tell you this now:

```
  = help: use `::<...>` instead of `<...>` if you meant to specify type arguments
  = help: or use `(...)` if you meant to specify fn arguments
```

I've only ever seen something like this when the types are ambiguous, which doesn't happen very often.

Comment: Why don't you need to specify the <T> in MyStruct when it's being created? Also, whats the difference between impl<T> and MyStruct<T>?

Comment: To expand on this: you can get what you want by using `MyStruct::<T>`, but as Shepmaster said, you really don't need to.

Comment: @Steve: Because it would be redundant with Rust's type inference.  As for the second question: the `<T>` in `impl<T>` *introduces* a type parameter; `MyStruct<T>` is simply using it.  It's not obvious in this specific case, but the distinction is important for more complicated `impl` blocks (such as on traits with `where` clauses).

Comment: You *do* need to specify the template, sometimes. In current versions of Rust, if I fail to get lifetimes correct, I get "lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content" *only* if I specify the template parameters. If I don't (leaving the compiler to infer them) I get a much more terse "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements" that doesn't show the lifetimes like the former error. It is good to know this syntax, and AFAICT, the book doesn't document this aspect.

Comment: what if test_field is not an Option<T>, but a T?

Comment: @fanlix I don't follow — you *have* to provide a value for every field when instantiating `MyStruct`. If you have a `T`, then you'll need a value for the `T`, which will already specify the concrete type. Perhaps if you provide a playground demonstrating what you  mean.

Comment: The section on Generics says nothing about struct. It is pointless to tell OP to go and read a reference which doesn't discuss this matter. The link posted in the question above provides no useful information to solving OPs question.