# How do I initialise a HashMap with specific key and value types?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I read the docs on [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/std/hash.html) and I understand that they can have [alternate custom types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/std/hash/alt_key_types.html). This example is given in the docs:

```rust
type Accounts<'a> = HashMap<Account<'a>, AccountInfo<'a>>;
let mut accounts: Accounts = HashMap::new();
```

I would prefer to not define an explicit type. I have a function that expects a mutable `HashMap<PathBuf, bool>`:

```rust
pub fn parse(
    visited: &mut HashMap<PathBuf, bool>,
    path: PathBuf,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

In my "main" function, I am calling "parse" like this:

```rust
let mut visited = HashMap::new();
parse(&mut visited, args.path)?;
```

The code compiles, but I would like to be more explicit and define the types when creating the `visited` variable. It looks like the following syntax is not correct:

```rust
let mut visited = HashMap<PathBuf, bool>::new();
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The [**compiler tells you the correct syntax**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad7711af077e0beeddacf76c3d61749b): ``help: use `::<...>` instead of `<...>` to specify type arguments``

Comment: I usually follow the compiler but this time I missed this hint.

Comment: Hey @Shepmaster I understand the StackOverflow practice of ruthlessly pruning redundant questions, but I don't think that I posted a duplicate of [What is the proper way to create a new generic struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399953/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-a-new-generic-struct). My question is more specific, it's about how to define the types when initialising a HashMap, whereas the other is about struct types. Would you consider removing the "duplicate" label?

Comment: A `HashMap` is a struct, so I don't see the difference. I would do the same for "how do I initialize a `Vec` or `BTreeMap` or ...". Remember that duplicates _are not bad_ and they are not "pruned". This will stay forever, as will the answers. Also, as the duplicate banner says: "This question already *has an answer* here", not "this is the same question as". It's about duplicate answers, not questions.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for explaining. I was unsure about how long duplicates stay on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters to generics in an expression (as opposed to a type) need an extra `::`. The correct syntax is:

```
let mut visited = HashMap::<PathBuf, bool>::new();
```

This construct is sometimes referred to as the "turbofish". I can't find a canonical reference about it (the word occurs [only once](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html?highlight=turbofish#non-operator-symbols) in the Book), but [this article](https://matematikaadit.github.io/posts/rust-turbofish.html) is pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Commented example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn parse(visited: &mut HashMap<PathBuf, bool>) {}

fn main() {
    // explicit type annotation
    let mut visited: HashMap<PathBuf, bool> = HashMap::new();
    
    // turbo-fish
    let mut visited = HashMap::<PathBuf, bool>::new();
    
    // the compiler can infer type from use
    let mut visited = HashMap::new();
    parse(&mut visited); // compiler can tell visited must be HashMap<PathBuf, bool>
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7e56dcb17282b59631c4029e5fb9f91)

Answer (score 1):

You can either bind to the generic parameters with the [turbofish](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) syntax:

```rust
let mut visited = HashMap::<PathBuf, bool>::new();
```

Or add a type annotation:

```rust
let mut visited: HashMap<PathBuf, bool> = HashMap::new();
```